# Understanding descent on elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof for finding the rank of an elliptic curve in the from $Y^2 = F(X)$ in the case where $F(X)$ has 3 rational roots.
I believe the book *Lectures on Elliptic Curves* by Cassels covers this in Chapter 15 entitled *The weak finite basis theorem*.

The proof treats the cases where F(X) has 3 rational roots, one rational root and  no rational roots together, however I'm only interested in the first case.

My main question is: in this specific case what is $\Theta$?

My second question is how do I interpret (iii) in this case in the homomorphism definition? What do points of the form $(a,0)$ map to?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $F(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)$, $\mathbb{Q}[\Theta]$ is $\mathbb{Q}^3$ and $\Theta$ is $(r_1,r_2,r_3)$.

For your second question, take for instance $a=r_1$ (in general, $a$ is some $r_i$), then the image of $(a,0)$ is the class in $\mathcal{M}$ of any $x=(\lambda,r_2-r_1,r_3-r_1)$ such that its norm (aka the product of these three elements) is the square of a nonzero rational.

Comment: Thanks for this. May I double check a couple of things about the ring $\mathbb{Q}(\Theta) = \mathbb{Q}^3$? 
Is $\mathbb{Q}(\Theta)^* = (\mathbb{Q}^3)^*$ the set of (a,b,c) with a,b,c $\in \mathbb{Q}$ and none of a,b,c are 0? (Or is it just you can’t have a=b=c=0?)

Comment: And secondly, is then $((\mathbb{Q}^3)^*)^2$ the set of (a,b,c) with a,b,c satisfying the above conditions and each of a,b,c is a square in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes, and yes. $\mathbb{Q}^3$ is really the ring where you do everything coordinatewise, so an element is invertible iff every coordinate has an inverse, and an element is a square iff every coordinate is a square.